# POST from iOS to MySQL database

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c

I'm trying to post data from my UITextFields to a MySQL database. The console says my connection is successful, but for some reason the data isn't posting to the database? Any idea as to why? Here's my code:

**ViewController.h**

```
-(IBAction)addParty:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstname;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *lastname;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *phone;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *email;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *guests;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *venueDetail;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)addParty:(id)sender
{

NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"guestfirst=%@&guestlast=%@", firstname.text, lastname.text];

NSData *postData = [strURL dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com/phpfile.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(conn)
{
    NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
}

}
```

**Post.php**

```
<?Php
include('connect.php');

if (isset ($_POST["guestfirst"]) && isset ($_POST["guestlast"])){
    $guestfirst = $_POST["guestfirst"];
    $guestlast = $_POST["guestlast"];
} else {
    $guestfirst = "none";
    $guestlast = "none";
}

// Insert value into DB
$sql = "INSERT INTO events (guestfirst, guestlast) VALUES ('$guestfirst', '$guestlast');";
$res = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($conn);

if($res) {          
$response = array('status' => '1');                 
} else {
die("Query failed");
}

echo json_encode($res);
exit();

?>
```

Comment: Is that your entire PHP file? If so, you're missing a few things.

Comment: Hi @RyanPendleton! The only thing not included is my included connection file (see edit). But otherwise that's the entire file... The connection works, my data just isn't posting to the database :/

Comment: Do you define $events in your connection file?

Comment: See above edit, @RyanPendleton. I define events in the above PHP file :) Let me know if that's correct...

Comment: What is it set to? Since you're using it in `mysql_fetch_assoc`, it appears it isn't a string. If you want to use `$events` in the query, you'll have to set it to `"events"` or whatever table you want to use.

Comment: Also, you're returning two individual JSON objects in one request. Odds are, your client library isn't going to support that.

Comment: @RyanPendleton Made the POST code into its own PHP file (makes things easier!) See above edit. Changed INSERT INTO 'events', but still nothing posts to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems I see with your current code.

1. When you're fetching existing articles, you are assigning the query to `$get_events`, but fetching from `$events`.
2. You're fetching before your insert. (maybe that's your intent?)
3. You output more than one JSON object
4. Your query uses `$events` rather than `` `events` ``.
5. You call `die()` if a MySQL error occurs, so you will never receive a JSON response saying there was an error.
6. You are using an old MySQL library AND your script is vulnerable to **SQL injection**.

Below is a version that should fix all of these except for the old library:

#### connect.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
mysql_select_db('testing');
?>
```

#### post.php

```
<?php
require_once("connect.php");

if (isset ($_POST["guestfirst"]) && isset ($_POST["guestlast"]))
{
    $guestfirst = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["guestfirst"]);
    $guestlast = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["guestlast"]);
}
else
{
    $guestfirst = "No Entry";
    $guestlast = "none";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `events` (guestfirst, guestlast) VALUES ('$guestfirst', '$guestlast');";
$res = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or $error = mysql_error();

if($res)
{
    $ret = array(
        'inserted' => true
    );
}
else
{
    $ret = array(
        'inserted' => false,
        'error' => $error
    );
}

mysql_close($conn);
echo json_encode($ret);
exit();
?>
```

#### list.php (or whatever else you called it)

```
<?php
require_once("connect.php");

$get_events = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `events`", $conn);
$articles = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_events))
{
    $articles[] = $row;
}

mysql_close($conn);
echo json_encode($articles);
exit();
?>
```

Comment: See above PHP file edits. Changed it to INSERT INTO 'events' and still nothing posts? Did I put it in correctly?

Comment: It's a backtick ` rather than an apostrophe '. Also, see my updated answer addressing other problems.

Comment: @Brittany I updated my answer and split the files to match your updated question

Comment: Just tried it. Still nothing posting to the database lol. Now I'm wondering if it has something to do with this... "events" is the table name. "guestfirst" and "guestlast" are names of the columns in the table. That said, the table has multiple rows. Perhaps it doesn't know which row it should be posting to?

Comment: That's not how a database works. Each time you post a record, it adds a new row to the table. It doesn't post to a row. Are there any errors in your PHP error file? What happens if you try to browse to the file in a browser?

Comment: Not to sound like a super newb, but where can I find the error file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63315/discussion-between-ryan-pendleton-and-brittany).